# Deformation invariance for tensor powers of the cotangent bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

For a family of smooth projective varieties over the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$, it's well-known that:

1. The Hodge numbers $h^q(X,\Omega_X^p)$ are constant in the family (since they are uppersemicontinuous functions that sum to the Betti numbers, which are topological invariants and hence constant);
2. The plurigenera $h^0(X,\omega_X^{\otimes m})$ are constant in the family for each $m \geq 0$ (by the famous result of Siu).

What is known about the deformation invariance of the dimension $h^0(X,(\Omega^1_X)^{\otimes m})$ of global sections of tensor powers of the cotangent bundle, where $m > 0$?  For instance, is this dimension constant in a family of relative dimension $3$ for every $m$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $(\Omega_X^1)^{\otimes n}$ contains $\mathrm{Sym}^n(\Omega_X^1)$ as a direct summand, by upper semi continuity of the complement, it suffices to give a counterexample for symmetric powers.

In Brotbek's thesis, an example of a family of smooth complete intersection surfaces in $\mathbb{P}^4$ is constructed which has jumping in the symmetric powers. The example can also be found on page 24 of [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.7848).